# How to expose an app docker build version?

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins

I need advice on how to be able to have expose application version end to end, from build to deployed version for a client.
Planning on having CI/CD pipelines to build/deploy docker images on K8 containers
for various app services for e.g. node express service with semantic versioning for build images of some sort.

I would like to be able to use this actual build version/tag all the way to API health check meta data for e.g..
is there any way to expose this actual docker image version to the end client?

Maybe embed the same version in health service api but ultimately expose the so that can be used by the application for logging and diagnostics.

What ultimately I like to do is build an artifact with a version from Jenkins and expose that same artifact version to the user. Rather than having different version mechanisms hard coded. I hope that makes sense.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What is "docker image version"? The image tag?

Comment: @LEQADA Yes tag is the correct docker metadata property for this.

Comment: You could tag the image, but also bake a version file into the image the health check could access.

Comment: @tadman so do I then update the version post build before I create the docker image?

Comment: I'd build with a version or build identifier already determined so you can bake that into the image. This could be a hash, an incremented number, or a timestamp, or a combination of any/all of those.

Comment: @tadman so is that derived from Jenkins and baked into the file pre-docker artifact build?

Comment: If you could do it in a way that's deterministic that's always great, you can always re-compute it later, but if Jenkins kicks out a unique ID of some sort you can use that'd do.

Comment: @Rubans See how I do it for my toy project here - github.com/taleodor/mafia-vue/blob/master/Dockerfile - notice the build gets labeled with the version and it's also put into version.html file. Note, it's done via GitHub Actions, but you can use same principle with Jenkins. You can see the exposed version at https://mafia.brolia.com/version.html. Hope this helps.

Comment: @taleodor had a look and that makes sense, thank you